# Unwrap elements with XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have large and complex documents which contain the following at various places in the document the following fragments

```
<a>foo<b>bar</b><a>
<a>foo<b>bar</b><b>hello</b><a>
```

which I want to transform to

```
<b>foobar<b> 
<b>foobar<b><b>hello</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following two template matchers:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="b"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::a/text()"/>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```